# Thymeleaf iterate list with alternate colors

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

In my Spring Boot project, I am iterating a Thymeleaf list like below:

```
<div th:each="filename: ${files}">
<div class="bold badge badge-primary" th:text="${filename}"></div>
</div>
```

**Question:** I am clueless on how can assign badge-primary and badge-secondary (bootstrap4.5) classes to alternate list items while iterating through them?

In simple words, first list item should have badge-primary class, second list item badge-secondary and so on.

Is it possible? If yes, then how? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `th:each`, Thymeleaf offers a mechanism useful for [keeping track of the status of your iteration](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status): the status variable. Per Thymeleaf documentation example, your code may look like the following ...

```
<div th:each="filename,iterStat: ${files}">
    <div class="bold badge badge-primary" th:class="'bold badge'" th:classappend="${iterStat.odd}? 'badge-primary' : 'badge-secondary'" th:text="${filename}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the use of `th:classappend`. I had not seen that before.

Comment: Thanks, @andrewjames . I found it quite useful when you need to keep the proper static view with the full list of classes, Thymeleaf `th:class` to only base list of classes and dynamic portion with `th:classappend`.

Comment: You could represent this as `th:class="|bold badge badge-${iterStat.odd ? 'primary' : 'secondary'}|"` and drop everything else if you want.

Comment: Brilliant. You are awesome. ! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton. !

Comment: @Metroids This one is very cool one-liner. Thanks for sharing!